# Computed property not updating on array when element added

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm currently using a computed property to sort an array contained in my model based on it's order (this is in the `slide-group` controller):

```
sortedSlides: function() {
    var slides = this.get('slides');
    var sortedSlides = slides.sortBy('order');
    return sortedSlides;
}.property('slides.@each.order')
```

A "Slide Group" contains a list of ordered slides. This works fine for reordering elements, as well as deleting slides. However, if I add a new slide, the property is never triggered and it doesn't appear.

Here's my save method for creating a new slide:

```
actions: {
    save: function() {      
        var slideGroup = this.modelFor('slide-group');

        var model = this.modelFor('slide-group.new-slide');
        model.set('slideGroup', slideGroup);
        model.save();

        this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('slide-group.index');
    },
}
```

I've also attempted to add `'slides'` to the `property()`, but it didn't help. **Why does the calculated property not update when adding a new slide?**

Version Info:
Ember: v1.7.0
Ember-CLI: v0.0.41

**Edit:** Here's my models, just for reference:

slide.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  slideGroup: DS.belongsTo('slide-group'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  order: DS.attr('number'),
  widgetType: DS.attr('string'),
  duration: DS.attr('number'),
  parameters: DS.attr()
});
```

slide-group.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  screens: DS.hasMany('screen', {async: true}),
  slides: DS.hasMany('slide', {async: true})
});
```

Comment: it may not apply to what you are doing, but I found I couldn't get an array to update until I started using the ember specific pushObject and popObject calls - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html

Comment: Perhaps try `property('slides.@each.order', 'slides.[]')`.

Comment: @torazaburo That didn't work either, but it did make me wonder: I'm only saving a new slide and assigning it a slide-group, but I'm not modifying the slides array directly on the slide-group. Do I need to update the relationship on both sides for it to update correctly? I've included my model above as well.

Comment: @sunrize920 It does appear to work if I update both sides of the model: `slideGroup.get('slides').pushObject(model);` on my save action. Should it really be necessary to update both sides of the model?

Comment: Ought to update, unclear as to why it would not be. However, it should be easy enough to validate the hypothesis that creating a new slide updates the `slides` property of the `slideGroup` model as I'm quite sure it should.

Comment: @torazaburo I added a `console.log(slideGroup.get('slides').get('length'));` before the save, after the save, and after the `pushObject` call, and the `save()` call does not update the length of slides (comes back with 1, 1, 2). I even put the log into a `.then()` function and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: See https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1532 for the issue related to this behavior.